# Changing Background Image through JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to change background image by using jquery. below is given html element i want to change its background image.

```
<div class="logo" />
```

and this is jquery code for changing background image.

```
$(".logo").css({ 'background-image' : 'url(test(1).png)' }
```

the problem is that when image name containing parenthesis `()` then its not working , but without parenthesis its working.. is there any solution to change background image regardless of its name.

Answer (score 5):

Put the value in double quotes:

```
$(".logo").css({ 'background-image' : 'url("test(1).png")' });
```

Also note that you don't need to use an object here as you're setting only one CSS rule:

```
$(".logo").css('background-image', 'url("test(1).png")');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".logo").css({ 'background-image' : 'url("' + imageUrl + '")' });
```